# C# Excel Interop Copy Cells by Row/Column - No error, but doesn't copy

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I feel that I'm missing something obvious. I have the following code with a problem setting the `Copy()` destination range:

```
var src = wsFlowData.get_Range("a2", "b10");
var dest = wsMergedData.Range["A142"];                                    //works as expected
//var dest = (Range)wsMergedData.Cells[1, 142];                           //no error, no copy
//var dest = wsMergedData.Cells[1, 142] as Range;                         //no error, no copy
//Range dest = wsMergedData.get_Range((Range)wsMergedData.Cells[1, 142]); //Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
src.Copy(dest);
```

As noted above, when I set the destination range explicitly, "A142", it works. When I try to use row/column numbers, it either continues without copying or throwing an exception. I've tried numerous other ways to set the range using integers with no success.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to do `Range rngCopy = worksheet.Cells.Range["A2", "B10"]`, and then `rngCopy.Copy()` ?  Note that `worksheet` is of type `Sheet` in this case.

Comment: Can you perhaps include some results, like before and afters? It may give a clearer idea of what you are trying to do as well as open the door for a different way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was a coding error. I used a bad example that had the row & column reversed. The corrected code is:

```
var src = wsFlowData.get_Range("a2", "b10");
var dest = (Range)wsMergedData.Cells[142, 1];
src.Copy(dest);
```